# Star of Afrika - Horseshoes confusion

Tags: afrikan-tahti

I'm a bit confused about the rules for horseshoes.In the rules it is said to put them aside.

What does that exactly entail?

Is it then so, that if you find them before the star is found....you just put them out of game. And when the star is found all other horseshoes found can now be taken by the player finding them instead of being put aside?
(which leads to the star player automatically winning in case no horseshoes are left?)

Or are the rules meant to work differently?

Comment: I edited the tag with the assumption that the question refers to [this game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/5130/afrikan-tahti)

Comment: @ikegami  thanks got too few points to create a tag myself so mechanics was the nearest tag I could go for.   Find it surprising still that the name is so different per language (the official one being afrikan tahti while in many countries it is known as star of africa)

Comment: Yeah, happens all the time. If I could create an alias for the tag, I would create `star-of-africa`. I don't know which of the two name is more appropriate, so I went with the one used by BGG

Comment: the tahti is also the one in wikipedia (english version) so I count it as official name as its not a german language game to start with (german version of wikipedia says "stern von Afrika").

Comment: "Star of Afrika" would be an accurate translation of the original name, there doesn't seem to be one official translation  to English. (But two different ones back in the 80s.) I can see why an English tag, or at least an alias, would be useful for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [rules on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afrikan_t%C3%A4hti),

> Before the star of Africa has been found, horseshoes are useless and are discarded. After the famous diamond has been found, however, they become effective substitutes for it. Taking a horseshoe to Cairo or Tangiers when another player has the star of Africa wins the game.

This does seem to imply that if *all* horseshoes are found before the Star, they will all be discarded and so the person who finds the Star has a guaranteed win.

Note that, according to the same article, the expansion changes this dynamic:

> In 2014, an expansion for the game called Retkikunnat ("The expeditions") was published, making the game more complex... As a new feature, it is now also possible to steal the Star of Africa from the player who found it.

Thus in the expansion, even if all horseshoes have been discarded, the Star can still be stolen so finding it does not guarantee that you will win.

Comment: For the first part: yes, exactly. (source: I'm Finnish.) The game is from the 50's, it's not a very good game compared to modern board games.